# momentjs - strange behave with startOf and endOf

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to get the start and the end a a specific day.

Here's the code:

```
var newDay, newDayEnd, newDayStart;

if (newDay === '') {
  newDay = moment();
}

newDay.subtract('day', 1);

newDayStart = newDay.startOf('day');    
newDayEnd = newDay.endOf('day');
```

I'm trying to debug it, and I noticed that when if goes trough the values are correct, but as soon as it reaches `newDay.endOf('day')` it sets all the variable to the end of the specified day (23.59.59)

I'm using the above function on button click. Every time I click a button, it goes back one day `(newDay.subtract('day', 1))` and I need to be able to get start and end of the new day (`newDay` variable)

Any help?
What am I doing wrong here? I don't understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment objects are mutable, so you have to [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) them before modifying  them.

As you can read from the [`endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) docs:

> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the end of a unit of time.

Working example:

```js
var newDay, newDayEnd, newDayStart;
newDay = moment().subtract(1, 'day');

newDayStart = newDay.clone().startOf('day');
newDayEnd = newDay.clone().endOf('day');
console.log(newDayStart.format(), newDayEnd.format());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```